Wiring Portable AC to Run at Max
I'd like to wire this portable AC to always run at max (compressor on and fan at max speed). I'm using it for a project where the temperature is going to be controlled by controlling the power to to the AC and I also need it cooler than the AC is willing to go with the default controls.
This portable AC is a bit more complex than the window ACs I've worked with in the past and I'm struggling to figure out how to wire the fan correctly. I believe I can get the compressor hardwired by connecting the black and blue wire from the compressor capacitor to load and neutral respectively but I'm not sure how to wire the fan.
In the picture, on the right are the wires going to the fan and the display. Below that are three bundles of cables that go to the two thermistors and water level sensor. On the right is 3 prong power, compressor(red/white/red), and splash motor(red/black/ground).
There are 6 wires going to the fan: red, orange, white, grey, black, and ground. Red and orange are connected to the black box in the top right of the picture which appears to be the fan capacitor and the white/grey/black go to connectors on the circuit board.
It would be great if the splash motor and display continued to work but not necessary.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!



This sounds like a good way to destroy your AC.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Hearth how so? The compressor/fans all run off of AC power normally and are just switched on and off by the circuit board. I'm just looking to bypass the circuit board. The circuit board and thermistors are just there to users can set a desired temperature

@KingLouis_CLXXII It's not usually a good idea to run a compressor continuously. They aren't generally designed for it.

@Hearth it's not going to be running continuously. I'm hooking it up to a controller than will turn it on/off by cutting power to the unit. I'm going to be using a compressor delay too. I just need the AC to run at max when it's powered -- it's not going to be powered continuously.

"I also need it cooler than the AC is willing to go with the default controls."
Consumer products are barely designed to operate at their maximum settings; extra capacity is lost profit.
